# Grouping by one column, comparing another, writing in a third

Tags: excel, vba

Having a bit of a problem with visualizing this. To start with here's a screen of my excel sample:

[image]

I'm trying to figure out how to:

1. Group all the SN's together so I can,
2. Compare the dates in the DOA and DOB columns for each row.  If they are equal, then
3. Write the word "Match" in the Result column.

edit:  The date comparison should be made only for the latest date for each SN.

I've highlighted the rows that should contain "Match" in their columns after code execution.

Is this possible to do with a VBA macro?

Comment: Not sure why you need VBA. A formula could easily do this: `IF(DOA = DOB, "Match", "")`

Comment: Oh I knew I was forgetting something.  I'll edit.

Comment: Latest DOB or DOA?

Comment: Still can be done with a formulaBTW

Comment: With Office 365: `=IF(AND(C2=MAXIFS(C:C,A:A,A2),C2=B2),"MATCH","")`  With earlier: `=IF(AND(C2=AGGREGATE(14,6,$C$2:$C$11/($A$2:$A$11=A2),1),C2=B2),"MATCH","")`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In case VBA is not a requirement:

If you have Office 365, use:

```
=IF(AND(C2=MAXIFS(C:C,A:A,A2),C2=B2),"MATCH","")
```

If you do not use:

```
=IF(AND(C2=AGGREGATE(14,6,$C$2:$C$11/($A$2:$A$11=A2),1),C2=B2),"MATCH","")
```

[image]

---

If your Excel is really old you will need to use:

```
=IF(AND(C2=MAX(IF($A$2:$A$11=A2,$C$2:$C$11)),C2=B2),"MATCH","")
```

This is an array formula and must be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when exiting edit mode.

Comment: Do you have something even older without the aggregate function?

Comment: A Formula Translation Attempt


=IF(AND(C2=MAX(IF($A$2:$A$11=A2,$C$2:$C$11)),C2=B2),"MATCH",""))


For all A-column value occurrences found in A-column range, checks the maximum of the corresponding values in C-column range against the C-column value and checks the C-column value against the B-column value and writes "MATCH", else writes "".